# VBA - excel 2016 vs excel 2019

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba code that runs flawlessly on my laptop that has excel 2019.  But when my colleague opens the same excel file and runs the same exact code it gives him a fault.  The only difference we can figure out is he has excel 2016.

More specifically here is the situation:

2 excel workbooks are open. One workbook is named "PegName". This is where the code module is at.
The other workbook is named "Weekly Template"

When the workbook PegName and the program is ran there is a line of code that is --
workbooks("Weekly Template").activate
This should then activate the other workbook.  It does on my laptop. And it faults out on my colleague's laptop.

Any ideas what is going on? Is VBA language different for excel 2016?  Other thoughts?

Mainly I've tried googling this and I can't find anything that would indicate that the vba code for activating a workbook is any different in excel 2016 than it is in excel 2019.  I have absolutely no idea why this won't run on my colleague's laptop.

Comment: Likely you need to include the file extension in the Workbook name.

Comment: Are both file paths identical?